# Find $\textstyle{\frac{1\cdot 2}{3!} +\frac{2\cdot2^2}{4!}+\frac{3\cdot2^3}{5!}+\frac{4\cdot2^4}{6!}+\cdots}$ up to n terms?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$
\frac{(1)2}{3!}  + \frac{(2)2^2}{4!} + \frac{(3)2^3}{5!}  + \frac{(4)2^4}{6!} + \cdots =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k\cdot 2^k}{(k+2)!}
$$

My attempt:

$$
\begin{align}
  e^x&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} \\
  (e^x)'&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!} \\
  x\cdot(e^x)'&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n}}{n!} \\
  x\cdot(e^x)'&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)x^{n}}{(n+2)!}
\end{align}
$$

After this attempt I realized exponential series is for infinite terms whereas the question concerns finite terms so approach may not work.

Can you please give any hints on the right approach to be tried?

Comment: What do you get by writing $i2^i  = (i + 2)2^i  - 2^{i + 1}$ and splitting your sum into two individual ones?

Comment: The sums should be from $n=0,$ at least in the first one.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before. It takes less than a minute to find a duplicate [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bk%20%3D%201%7D%5En%20%7B%5Cfrac%7B%7Bk2%5Ek%20%7D%7D%7B%7B(k%20%2B%202)!%7D%7D%7D%24)

Comment: @MartinR Are there any other ways to check if questions have already been answered other than looking at the similar suggestions that popup while the question is being typed. I specifically checked if the question has been answered in all those suggestion but it seems the logistics of how the concerned question was posed differently didn't make it show up in the similar suggestions.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/42969. My favorite tool is Approach0, you can check it with the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, the site search does not work well with mathematical formulas, but Approach0 does a really good job. If you have more questions about it: There is a dedicated chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46148/in-the-search-of-a-question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using my hint in the comments,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{k2^k }}{{(k + 2)!}}} & = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{(k + 2)2^k  - 2^{k + 1} }}{{(k + 2)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{2^k }}{{(k + 1)!}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{2^{k + 1} }}{{(k + 2)!}}} \\ & = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{2^k }}{{(k + 1)!}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 2}^{n + 1} {\frac{{2^k }}{{(k + 1)!}}}  = 1 - \frac{{2^{n + 1} }}{{(n + 2)!}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: This has been asked and answered before. It takes less than a minute to find a duplicate [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bk%20%3D%201%7D%5En%20%7B%5Cfrac%7B%7Bk2%5Ek%20%7D%7D%7B%7B(k%20%2B%202)!%7D%7D%7D%24)

Answer (score 2):

Making the problem more general, write
$$\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{m\, x^m}{(m+2)!}=\frac 1 x\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{ x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}-\frac 2 {x^2}\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{ x^{m+2}}{(m+2)!}$$
$$\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{ x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}=e^x\frac{ \Gamma (n+2,x)}{(n+1)!}-x-1$$
$$\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{ x^{m+2}}{(m+2)!}=e^x\frac{ \Gamma (n+3,x)}{\Gamma (n+3)}-\frac{x^2}{2}-x-1$$ Recombining everything
$$\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{m\, x^m}{(m+2)!}=\frac{x+2}{x^2}-\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+2)!}+e^x\frac {x-2}{x^2}\frac{  \Gamma (n+3,x)}{  (n+2)!}$$

You are lucky with $x=2$
$$\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{m\, 2^m}{(m+2)!}=1-\frac{2^{n+1}}{ (n+2)!}$$

Comment: This has been asked and answered before. It takes less than a minute to find a duplicate [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bk%20%3D%201%7D%5En%20%7B%5Cfrac%7B%7Bk2%5Ek%20%7D%7D%7B%7B(k%20%2B%202)!%7D%7D%7D%24)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer: Just mistakenly thought that we need to find the sum to infinity.

Given, $\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{m\cdot 2^m}{(m+2)!}$. We put $m=n-2 $ and thus the series becomes $\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{(n-2)\cdot 2^{n-2}}{n!}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{(n-2)\cdot 2^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{n\cdot 2^n}{n!}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{2\cdot 2^n}{n!}=A+B(say)$. Where $A,B$ denotes the first and second sum respectievly.
Now, $$A=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{n\cdot 2^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\frac{1}{2}(e^2-1-2).$$ Recall that $\displaystyle e^x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ now put $x=2$.

Similarly, $$\displaystyle B=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{2}(e-1-2-\frac{2^2}{2!})=\frac{1}{2}(e^2-5).$$

So $\displaystyle A+B=\frac{1}{2}(e^2-3-e^2+5)=1.\square$

Hope this works.

Comment: The question was about a finite sum of $n$ terms. The answer will depend on $n$.

Comment: Blunder of the century! Thanks for noticing that. Literally all the effort was lost! :D

Comment: I do not believe there is a formula for the finite sum, but you could probably use Taylor's theorem to get a good approximation

Comment: Yes! Sum after n-terms are possible with no error in AP, GPs but in case of exponential or trigonometric functions we can hardly approximate them.

Comment: @AlanAbraham Really? $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{k2^k }}{{(k + 2)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{(k + 2)2^k  - 2^{k + 1} }}{{(k + 2)!}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{2^k }}{{(k + 1)!}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{2^{k + 1} }}{{(k + 2)!}}}  \\ = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{2^k }}{{(k + 1)!}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 2}^{n + 1} {\frac{{2^k }}{{(k + 1)!}}}  = 1 - \frac{{2^{n + 1} }}{{(n + 2)!}}.
$$

Comment: @Gary my bad. I totally missed a telescoping solution. Nice solution!